# My loop condition isn't being met

Tags: c++, string, std

For some reason this C++ below keeps returning false.  Any help would be apprected!  I would include more source but it's in LibPQ

```
std::string one = "stringa";
std::string two = "stringb";

std::string three = "stringa";
std::string four = "stringb";

if( one.compare( three ) == 0 && two.compare( four ) == 0 )  {

  return true;
} else {

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why don't (or can't) you use `==`?

Comment: It's a string thing... to compare a string you need it

Comment: @Roland: This is not java - in C++ you can compare strings using the equals-operator.

Comment: @RolandSams, `if (one == three && two == four)` is perfectly fine with `std::string`.

Comment: @RolandSams such a requirement is in Java, in C++ `==` does the right thing when comparing strings

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can... I will try it.

Comment: are you missing one `{`  after if?

Comment: If you're interested, `std::string` overloads `operator==`, something not possible in Java.

Comment: FWIW, [works here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/J9nS3$0).

Comment: why not just : `return (one == three && two == four);`?

Comment: @RolandSams it works as intended http://ideone.com/zdNa6M

Comment: ok maybe I have worse problems... Thanks for all your help

Comment: you could post more relative code. but this piece of code worked as expected.

Comment: Roland, you would have noticed your code works had you compiled and tested the code you actually posted before posting it.  That would have been a better move, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
std::string one = "stringa";
std::string two = "stringb";

std::string three = "stringa";
std::string four = "stringb";

if( one == three && two == four ) {

  return true;
} else {

  return false;
}
```

Comment: missing { after if, just like question missed

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you don't have an { after your if. Try this

```
std::string one = "stringa";
std::string two = "stringb";

std::string three = "stringa";
std::string four = "stringb";

if( one.compare( three ) == 0 && two.compare( four ) == 0 )
{
  return true;
} else {

  return false;
}
```

Btw, does your code even complie with that?

Comment: Maybe it compiles when we know the context the snippet is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below :

```
#include "iostream" 

using namespace std; 

std::string one = "amit"; 
std::string two = "kumar"; 
std::string three = "amit"; 
std::string four = "kumar"; 

bool strcomp() 
{ 
    if (one.compare(three) == 0 && two.compare(four) == 0) 
    { 
        return true; 
    } 

    return false; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    if (strcomp()) 
    { 
       cout<<"Equal"<<endl; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
       cout<<"Defferent"<<endl; 
    } 

}
```

OUTPUT : Equal